# Objective-C error message: Multiple methods named 'setBounds:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
@implementation Circle

- (void) setFillColor: (ShapeColor) c
{
  fillColor = c;
}

- (void) setBounds: (ShapeRect) b
{
    bounds = b;
}

- (void) draw
{
    NSLog (@"drawing a circle at (%d %d %d %d) in %@",
        bounds.x, bounds.y,
        bounds.width, bounds.height,
        colorName(fillColor));
}

@end // Circle

void drawShapes (id shapes[], int count)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        id shape = shapes[i];
        [shape draw];
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  id shapes[1];
  ShapeRect rect0 = { 0, 0, 10, 30 };
  shapes[0] = [Circle new];
  [shapes[0] setBounds: rect0];
  [shapes[0] setFillColor: kRedColor];
  drawShapes (shapes, 1);
  return (0);
}
```

I wrote this code block from the book called "Learn Objective-C on the mac and I got the error message from the title and this error "Passing '__strong id *' to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained id *' changes retain/release properties of pointer"

As a warning, I got this "Expression which evaluates to zero treated as a null pointer constant of type 'CGColorRef _Nullable' (aka 'struct CGColor *')"

I would like to know how can I solve that.
Here is the "@interface"

```
@interface Circle : NSObject
{
    
    ShapeColor  fillColor;
    ShapeRect   bounds;
    
}
- (void) setFillColor: (ShapeColor) fillColor;
- (void) setBounds: (ShapeRect) bounds;
- (void) draw;

@end // Circle
```

Comment: The book is a bit old. If you switch off "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" in the build settings, the error will go away.

Comment: Do you recommend any book for Objective-C?